# apk fails to run on some devices

Tags: android, apk, coronasdk

I have a quick question. I have built an app in Corona SDK (Version 2012.878). My app works fine on my Galaxy S. But it fails to install on HTC Wildfire S. 
Is it because of CPU? Are there some other reasons? Is there a way to know, on which devices app will fail to install?

Thank you

Comment: i think you should check the logcat.

Comment: What do you mean with "fails to install"? Any error message? Do both test devices use the same Android version?

Comment: Galaxy S firmware is Android 2.2.1; Wildfire 2.2.3, so firmware is even more recent. I heard something about Corona SDK supports not all CPU. Maybe this is the problem...

Comment: P.S. error message is "Failed to install example.apk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTC Wildfire has an ARMv6 processor. You need a device with ARMv7 or later for Corona apps to install. There is a very old version of Corona SDK that supports ARMv6, but it's not supported anymore and I don't think it's that easy to get your hands on either.

Comment: That`s very sad. I think there are quite a lot devices vith older processor. Thank you for the answer :)